# ExtJs Two way binding between parent and child component

Tags: javascript, extjs, data-binding, viewmodel, extjs6

I have two components: A panel and a custom text field.
The panel has a viewmodel and I want to bind a value (called `testData`) from that viewmodel to a property (called `test`) of the custom text field.
That works fine ...basically.
But when the `test` property of the text field is changed, the `testData` in the viewmodel of the panel does not update accordingly. I mean when the `test` property of the child element (the textfield) is modified, the `testData` property of the panel's viewmodel should contain the same value that is in `test`, just like a normal two-way bind.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but here is what I've tried to far:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/20pu&view/editor

```
Ext.define('MyMain', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.main',

    width: '100%',
    bodyPadding: 10,

    viewModel: {
        data: {
            testData: 'Example Data'
        }
    },

    bind: {
        title: '{testData}'
    },

    items: {
        xtype: 'myField',
        bind: {
            test: '{testData}'
        }
    }
})

Ext.define('MyField', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Text',
    alias: 'widget.myField',
    fieldLabel: 'Data',
    width: '100%',

    config: {
        test: null // when test is changed, it should also affect the {testData} bind of the main component, causing the title to change
    },

    setTest(value) {
        this.test = value + ' modified!' // because of the bind, this /should/ automatically get appied to the viewmodel's `testData` and thus to the panel title
        this.setValue(this.test) // whenever the `test` property is changed, we write the contents to the value of the text field (just to visualize the `test` property).
        // But as you can see, the panel title will still just say `Example Data` and not `Example Data modified!` as it should.
    },
    getTest(){
        return this.test
    }
})

Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            items: [{
                xtype: 'main'
            }]
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: first of all the `config`is there as a default value and you create your component with a parameter `test` which will overrule the default value in `test`.

Comment: It wouldn't really matter if the config value could only be set once from the parent component. My main problem is that changing the test value doesn't affect the viewmodel property of the parent component. Any ideas how that could be solved?

Comment: you don't have any `test` in the parent..only a `testData`

Comment: Yes, well, I want to connect the two so that changing `test` in the child component changes 'testData' in the parent's viewmodel.

Comment: but you didn't formulate the question like that, that's misleading. I will have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Update***: (after reading your comments on other answers)

In general, mentioning the property in the `config` block and include it in [`publishes`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/api/Ext.Component.html#cfg-publishes) will make any property two-way bindable.

ExtJS will generate the getter and setter methods for it. The setter method takes care of binding. Now, whenever anyone updates the property value (using the setter), the new value will be passed on to the bound viewModel and in turn to the other components.

Accessing the property directly, `this.test` or `this.viewModel.data.testData`  and assigning values to them will not be reflected in the controls bound to this property.

In case you are providing an implementation for the setter function (`setTest`) of a published property, ensure that `this.callParent(...)` gets called from it.

The usage of field's `value` property to display the contents of `test` caused the earlier confusion. Here is a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/20vi&view/editor) with two-way bindable `test` property without any special handling in the `MyField` class.

Click on the 'Get test' button, the value should be 'Example Data' (from viewModel).

'Set testData' button will update the value in the viewModel. Use the 'Get test' button again to verify that the value of `test` has also been updated.

'Set test' button assigns a new value to the field's `test` property and this will be reflected in the panel's title.

---

Have a look at this [forked fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/20v7&view/editor).

In your implementation, the `setTest` method is directly changing the value of `this.test` to `value + ' modified!'`. This will not update the value of `testData` in viewModel as binding works via the getter and setter functions implemented of the properties specified in the config.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change title while changing `Textfield` then you have to bind `value` property because changing textfield's value only changes value property of field.

```
 bind: {
            test: '{testData}',
            value : '{testData}'
        },
```

If you don't want to bind it with value then on `change` event you have to set value of `test` property.

```
listeners : {
                change : function(field, newValue, oldValue, eOpts ){
                    field.setTest(newValue);
                }
            }
```

Please refer [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/20v6&view/editor).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to make the `test` config [twoWayBindable](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-twoWayBindable).

> This object holds a map of config properties that will update their
>   binding as they are modified.

Secondly, you don't need to define getters and setters for the [config](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Class.html#cfg-config) object, in your case.

> Each config item will have its own setter and getter method
>   automatically generated inside the class prototype during class
>   creation time, if the class does not have those methods explicitly
>   defined.

You might to, but it will override the default methods which take care of updating the binding, among other things.

> By standardize this common pattern, the default generated setters
>   provide two extra template methods that you can put your own custom
>   logic into, i.e: an "applyFoo" and "updateFoo" method for a "foo"
>   config item, which are executed before and after the value is actually
>   set, respectively.

The [twoWayBindable](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-twoWayBindable) config relies on the update template method, and when you specify your own setter, the update method will never get called, and the binding won't be updated.

> In other words, when leveraging the config feature, you mostly never
>   need to define setter and getter methods explicitly. Instead, "apply"
>   and "update" methods should be implemented where necessary.

So, in your example, here are the steps you need to take:

1. Remove the `setTest` and `getTest` method declarations.
2. Add the `twoWayBindable` config containing `test`.

   ```
   twoWayBindable: ['test']`
   ```
3. Hook up any additional logic into the `applyTest` or  `updateTest` template methods. For example, updating the field value after the test value gets set.

   ```
   updateTest(testValue) {
       this.setValue(testValue)
   }
   ```

Here is the working fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/20rs&view/editor

Comment: Doesn't seem to solve the problem. When the text field is changed, the title of the panel is supposed to get the same value as the text field. The panel's title should simply synchronize with the test property of the text field whenever it changes.

Comment: When the text field is changed, its `value` changes and not the `test` config. I thought your `test` config is changed somewhere else. Why would you need the `test` config anyway? Why not just bind `testData` to `value`? Here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/20se&view/editor

Comment: The test property is the whole point. I'm well aware that two way binding on the value works. I honestly don't even care abount the value property itself, I just made use of it to visualize the contents of the test property.

Comment: @Forivin Ok! As far as reflecting the `test` value to the panel title, I think that my answer covers this. When you press the button and the `test` value changes, the title is updated. Now you are saying that `When the text field is changed, the title of the panel is supposed to get the same value as the text field.`. But when the field changes, its `value` config changes. Could you please update you question explaining in more details the relation between `test` and `value`? Should `value` update `test`?

Comment: Okay, I updated the question. I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to be able to bind custom class properties you need to list these in the [`twoWayBindable`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-twoWayBindable) config.
2. Don't modify the value to be set in the setter and don't call the setter recursively. It is better to write an `update<Fieldname>()` function. Those are meant to handle updates in your view and they usually don't modify your data structures.
3. Based on 2.): Override the view update function of the form field to catch changes done to the value.

Here is the complete fiddle:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/218m&view/editor

Some things to note here:

- after 3 seconds, the ViewModel testData value is updated
- after 6 seconds, the setTest() setter of the field is called
- after 9 seconds, the setValue() method from your input field is triggered
- at the end, you could change the input field value to change the panel title

This is to illustrate the various scenarios.